# Out of bounds, why?

Tags: java, arrays

I've discovered strange (at least for me) exception throw. Let me make it short enough. There is a method which returns an array with random values. In main method I use foreach loop to show every value stored in my array.

```
tab[i] = (int) ((Math.random()*10));
```

It works fine until I set the minimum value.

```
tab[i] = (int) ((Math.random()*10)+1);
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   10

Could someone explain this to me? I have no clue how does +1 on right side affect size of array.

Edit: Full code

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Arrays {

    static private int[] makeArray(int wide) {

        int[] tab = new int[wide];

        for(int i=0;i<tab.length;i++) {
            tab[i] = (int) ((Math.random()*10)+1);
        }

        return tab;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tabby[] = makeArray(10);

        for(int i : tabby) {
            System.out.println(tabby[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is in the value of `i`. Use an `if` statement to evaluate it before setting something in the array.

Comment: You need to example the line where this error occurs.  I guess you are looking up `array[t[i]]` and as `t[i]` can be 10 and your `array` is only 10 elements you get this error.  This is where using a debugger should help you solve your problem.

Comment: If the array is size 10, i should be <= 9.

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed

Comment: You need to show your loop and how you set `i` to get a complete answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for (int i : tabby)` is giving you the values in the `tabby` array, not the indexes (zero through nine) of the array. Just do `System.out.println(i)`.

edit: To elaborate, you should be seeing this program throw the exception intermittently because your random number assignment has a one in ten chance of producing the number 10, and `tabby[10]` is going to be out of bounds.